# How scan all <span> tags of a page and get or set a content?

Tags: javascript

I have this following code that scans all `<input>` tags of a page and then you are able to set you to get a value to this tag.

```js
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {

  input[i].value = "123";

}
```

Now, how can I do the same with a `<span>` tag, which I already know does not have a property called **value**?

Comment: so you read the html or text of the element...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question was somewhat confusing, but I'll give my best answer:

Just take your code for the inputs, and change a few key componenents:

```
var span = document.getElementsByTagName('span');//Replace "input" with "span"

for (var i = 0; i < span.length; i++) {//Again, replacing "input" with "span"

  var textInsideTheSpan = span[i].textContent;//Reading text inside span
  span[i].textContent = "Your text here";//Writing text to the span

}
```

The key here is in the `.textContent`, a property of the javascript `Node` object, which can be read or written to,  depending on your application. Everything else simply replaced "input" with "span".

Answer (score 0):

Just use following:

```js
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  var text = spans[i].innerHTML;
  if (text.length == 0) {
    spans[i].innerHTML = i; //Some text
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to set the text inside `span`:

```js
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  input[i].textContent = "123";
}
```

```html
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
```